# Is it possible to put an iframe inside a Facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook, fbml

According to the [Facebook developer roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap), it will soon be possible to put iframes inside page tabs but it's not yet available. I came across this Store Locator on Coach page which uses an iframe to display a Google map inside a tab :

http://www.facebook.com/Coach?v=app_168904438199&ref=ts

Looking at the source code, I see the map really is inside an iframe. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in STATIC FBML pages you CAN'T USE IFRAMES - no matter what FBML code you put in there, facebook have specifically made the code not work in in business page/tab static fbml pages - my guess is so they can prevent people setting up Amazon stores or other content that uses IFrame (spammers and spyware often use iframes) - the updates are in their 2010 wiki - so it's probabley also a security thing.

I frames can still be used on developers canvas pages apparently but the customer has to click on an image for it to activate rather than the iframe automatically loading - again this is probably a security issue to prevent driveby downloads - where zwinky and similar toolbars are forced onto people computers in the background via iframes without their knowledge.

However some say it does work although you need a user to click on it before it works. if you can live with that then go for it.

```
<a onClick="outside_location.setInnerFBML(location_two);" style="cursor: pointer;"><center>→our website</center></a><div id="outside_location"> <fb:iframe width="730" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www.fborder.com/" /> </div>
<fb:js-string var="location_two"> <fb:iframe width="730" height="600" frameborder='0' src='http://www.fborder.com/' /> </fb:js-string> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> var outside_location = document.getElementById('outside_location'); </script>
```

check out this post. people have got it to work. and some say it wont work for the obvious reasons. such as security and so on. but give it a go regardless.

http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=4949752878&topic=7081

**PK**

Comment: So basically, the Store locator on Coach page is either a special partnership with Facebook or a hack that is not approved by Facebook?

Comment: its just an image which you have to click efore it gets activated. otherwise you cannot get an iframe yet thats activated straight away for security reasons. you can still try the code some people say it works some people say that its not possible
but thats the correct information ive given. sometimes it works because some companies have partnership with facebook themselves, youll even notice some of the pages look completely different compared to normal facbook pages because of partnership reasons